# Finding discrete logarithm with baby-step-giant-step algorithm

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I am trying to use the [Baby Step Giant Step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) algorithm to find discrete logarithm in:
$$a^x= B  \pmod p$$
with using BSGS:
$$x = im+j$$ 
$$a^j = B a^{-im}$$ where 
$m = \sqrt{p}$

Wikipedia says:

> A cyclic group of order $p$, having a generator $\alpha$ and an element $B$.

But $p$ is a 158 bit number. Hence $m$ is too large and I know that $j$ is not a very big number,  $j < k$, where $k \ll n$.
I try to limit test values for $j$ and $i$ by defining $n$ as the next prime of $k$, but in this case I have this problem:

$$x = im+j \pmod {\operatorname{nextPrime}(k)}$$

$$a^x = B\pmod p$$
and when I try $B a^{-im}$ it does not give me $a^j$  because $B$ is actually $a^x \pmod p$ and I cannot find it in the lookup table I have created using values of $a^j$.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems that you are not using the algorithm in its correct form, but in a form modified by you for reasons that are not at all clear. Presumably, your modified algorithm is not correct.

Comment: yes I am aware of that , but if i just use algorithm as it is by doing sqrt(p) tries where p is a huge prime number then it will be worse than exhaustive searching.I know that k is a small number and I feel like I should take advantage of that

Comment: What are $n$ and $k$?

Comment: sorry,n is same as p actually a big prime number , I edited the question. k is a upper bound we know on j hence $$j<k$$

Answer (score 3):

To search for the values $a^x$ in the range $0 < x < k$, what you need to do is set $m = \sqrt{k}$ (rounded up), and then do the Baby Step/Giant Step algorithm for $0 \le i, j < m$.

That is, you generate the values $a^0, a^1, ..., a^{m-1}$ and the values $B\cdot a^{-0}, B\cdot a^{-m}, B\cdot a^{-2m}, ..., B\cdot a^{-(m-1)m}$; if $x<k$, then there will be a colliding pair $a^j = B\cdot a^{-im} = a^x \cdot a^{-im}$ with $x = j +im$

Comment: Thank you.But B is again in mod p  I think same issue still exists there.

Comment: @usry: no, what I wrote works just fine; just because you compute $a^j$ and $B \cdot a^{-im}$ modulo $p$ doesn't mess anything up.